# What is the Reconversion Key in 10.7.5?

Tags: japanese

On Japanese keyboards, there is a Reconversion key beside the space bar, which when highlighting some Kanji in Japanese will allow you to convert it to different Kanji (shows a dropdown of options). Apparently this was at one point ctrl+1, or ctrl+2, but neither work for me now. Ideas?

> There are some differences between MacOS 10.1 and MacOS 10.2 for "Reconversion" 
>   in Japanese IME pencel menu and short-cut keys, e.g. the correct short-cut for 
>   JA "Reconversion" on MacOS 10.2 should be "Control + 2", but not "Control + 1" 
>   on MacOS 10.1. "Control + 1" on MacOS 10.2 is assigned to a different function 
>   other than "Reconversion".

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as Reverse Conversion (⌃⇧R).

[image]

You can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) to get a separate 変換 key.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>henkan</name>
<identifier>private.henkan</identifier>
<inputmode_only>JAPANESE</inputmode_only>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::R, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```